# iptables gives me the error "can't initialize iptables NAT"

Tags: linux, iptables, nat

I am trying to use `iptables` and it is giving me the following error

```
root@vikkyhacks:~# iptables -t NAT -L
iptables v1.4.18: can't initialize iptables table `NAT': Table does not exist (do you need to insmod?)
Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.
```

**How do I fix this ?** I am running `Ubuntu 13.10` with

```
root@vikkyhacks:~# uname -a
Linux vikkyhacks 3.11.0-12-generic #19-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 9 16:20:46 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure you use lowercase for `nat`. Case matters in the Linux world, so `NAT` and `nat` are two different tables.

Comment: never could have thought it would be so simple !!!

Answer (score 0):

Either

```
1: You could try modprobe iptable_nat or insmod iptable_nat  
     If the above succeeds you need to load  iptable_filter the same way.
2. You need to upgrade iptables to 1.4.19.1 or higher. 
3. Upgrade the kernel.
```